# Error when creating the Album module in Zend Framework 3

Tags: php, zend-framework3

Good morning to the community, I need help to create the Album module in Zend Frameword 3, following tutorial 3. I have the following error:

```
<?php
[ModelAlbumTable::class =>

function ($container)
{
$tableGateway = $container->get(ModelAlbumTableGateway::class);

return new ModelAlbumTable($tableGateway);
}

, ModelAlbumTableGateway::class =>

function ($container)
{
$dbAdapter = $container->get(AdapterInterface::class);

$resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
$resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new ModelAlbum());
return new TableGateway('album', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
}

, ], ];
} // Add this method: 
public function getControllerConfig() 
{ return [ 'factories' => [ Controller\AlbumController::class => 
 function($container) { 
return new Controller\AlbumController( $container- 
get(Model\AlbumTable::class) ); }, ], ]; } }
 ?>
```

**Error is as below:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException: Module (Album) could not be initialized. in C:\xampp\htdocs\marycela\vendor\zendframework\zend-modulemanager\src\ModuleManager.php:203 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\marycela\vendor\zendframework\zend-modulemanager\src\ModuleManager.php(175): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModuleByName(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent)) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\marycela\vendor\zendframework\zend-modulemanager\src\ModuleManager.php(97): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModule('Album') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\marycela\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(322): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->onLoadModules(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent)) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\marycela\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(171): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent)) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\marycela\vendor\zendframework\zend-modulemanager\src\ModuleManager.php(120): Zend\EventManager\Event in C:\xampp\htdocs\marycela\vendor\zendframework\zend-modulemanager\src\ModuleManager.php on line 203

module.config.php

```html
namespace Album;

use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;

return 
[
    'router' => 
    [
        'routes' => 
        [
            'album' => 
            [
                'type'    => Segment::class,
                'options' => 
                [
                    'route' => '/album[/:action[/:id]]',
                    'constraints' =>
                    [
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ],
                    'defaults' => 
                    [
                        'controller' => Controller\AlbumController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ]    
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'view_manager' => 
    [
        'template_path_stack' => 
        [
            'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
    ],
];
```

modules.confing.php

```html
return [
    'Zend\ServiceManager\Di',
    'Zend\Session',
    'Zend\Log',
    'Zend\Form',
    'Zend\Db',
    'Zend\Cache',
    'Zend\Router',
    'Zend\Validator',
    'Application',
    'Album', 
];
```

Album.Controller.phph

```html
namespace Album\Controller;

use Album\Model\AlbumTable;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class AlbumController extends AbstractActionController
{
     // Add this property:
    private $table;

    // Add this constructor:
    public function __construct(AlbumTable $table)
    {
        $this->table = $table;
    }
    
    public function indexAction()
    {
          return new ViewModel([
            'albums' => $this->table->fetchAll(),
        ]);
    }

    public function addAction()
    {
    }

    public function editAction()
    {
    }

    public function deleteAction()
    {
    }
}
```

AlbumTable.php

```html
namespace Album\Model;

use RuntimeException;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGatewayInterface;

class AlbumTable
{
    private $tableGateway;

    public function __construct(TableGatewayInterface $tableGateway)
    {
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    }

    public function fetchAll()
    {
        return $this->tableGateway->select();
    }

    public function getAlbum($id)
    {
        $id = (int) $id;
        $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(['id' => $id]);
        $row = $rowset->current();
        if (! $row) 
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(sprintf(
                'Could not find row with identifier %d',
                $id
            ));
        }

        return $row;
    }

    public function saveAlbum(Album $album)
    {
        $data = 
        [
            'artist' => $album->artist,
            'title'  => $album->title,
        ];

        $id = (int) $album->id;

        if ($id === 0) 
        {
            $this->tableGateway->insert($data);
            return;
        }

        if (! $this->getAlbum($id)) 
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(sprintf(
                'Cannot update album with identifier %d; does not exist',
                $id
            ));
        }

        $this->tableGateway->update($data, ['id' => $id]);
    }

    public function deleteAlbum($id)
    {
        $this->tableGateway->delete(['id' => (int) $id]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please either translate your title into English or translate your question body to Spanish and post it on [es.so].

Comment: your module config is wrong somewhere

Comment: you can see the mudule.config.php in: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/157801/error-al-crear-el-m%C3%B3dulo-%C3%81lbum-en-zend-framework-3-siguiendo-el-tutorial-3

Comment: Flagged for moderator to close as duplicated on Spanish SO: [link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/157801/error-al-crear-el-m%C3%B3dulo-%C3%81lbum-en-zend-framework-3-siguiendo-el-tutorial-3) (provided  by OP in comments).